# What is non-micro USB connector?

Tags: usb, connector

I'm reading an article which is about [wearable smart watches](http://www.phonearena.com/news/To-wearable-or-not-to-wearable_id64018).

> To their credit, many of the manufacturers have made charging a
> **non-micro USB** charging affair, though Motorola’s Moto 360 is probably
> the most handsome execution of the idea. Sony, for reasons unknown has
> chosen the ol' plug-it-in approach with the Smartwatch 3. None of
> these methods would matter to me if didn’t have to go through the
> exercise on a daily basis though.

As above context says Motorola's Moto 360 smart watch uses `non-micro` connector, I found following image as [Moto 360 connector](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/100824/p/2815,9141) (which is micro USB connector) :

[image]

Now, I'm confusing what is non-micro USB and how it looks like?

Comment: Looks like inductive charging.

Comment: Maybe "non-micro USB connector" simply means "not a micro-USB connector"

Comment: @PeterBennett So why author didn't say simply a USB connector instead of non-micro USB connector?

Answer (score 2):

I guess they mean the interface between that charger and the phone (or smartwatch in that case). So you don't have to plug in the micro-USB cable directly into the phone but just place the phone onto the charging dock.